# How to check flash file fully loaded and then fadout loader icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash

I am using flash file in my page but as it is to long so take some load till my page show white screen

For that I put loading icon but how can i check that my flash file fully loaded so I can fadeout that icon

My code is as below

I call Flash in Iframe

```
<iframe class="frm" src="Car-speakers-590x90.swf" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

And I want to call below function when above swf file fully loaded

```
setTimeout(function() {
 $(".loading-box").fadeOut("slow");
}, 10000);
```

So can you help me out how to do this by javascript or jQuery or any other stuff?

Answer (score 0):

Use [onload](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp) event

```
$('#theiframe').on("load", function() {
  $(".loading-box").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Comment: Thanks is this unload event call only after swf file fully loaded because it is in large size

Comment: Yes, the onload event occurs when an object (a swf file in your case) has been loaded.